# multiply pandas column with a number in python

Tags: python, pandas, string, numpy, dataframe

I am trying to multiply the price column with integers but it is not happening.

```
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    a=row['price']
    row['price'] = a[1:]
    b = row['price'].split(' ')[1]
```

So I want to multiply by 100000 where price has 'L' in it and by 10000000 where price has 'Cr' in it.
For example, the first cell has 50.0 L so the output should be 5000000.0
I used the `dtype` and the output was `dtype('O')`

```
    price   area    type    price per sq feet   Address
0   50.0 L  650      1      7.69                Mankhurd
1   1.15 Cr 650      1      17.69               Chembur
2   95.0 L  642      1      14.80               Bhandup West
3   1.6 Cr  650      2      24.61               Goregaon East
5   88.0 L  570      1      15.44               Borivali East
```

I would appreciate the help.
Thank Yoo

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you can try with `series.str.extract` with `series.map` and multiplication:

```
d = {"L":100000,"Cr":10000000}
pat = '|'.join(d.keys())
mapped = df['price'].str.extract('('+pat+')',expand=False).map(d)
df['price'] = pd.to_numeric(df['price'].str.replace(pat,''),errors='coerce') * mapped
```

---

```
print(df)

        price  area  type  price per sq feet        Address
0   5000000.0   650     1               7.69       Mankhurd
1  11500000.0   650     1              17.69        Chembur
2   9500000.0   642     1              14.80   Bhandup West
3  16000000.0   650     2              24.61  Goregaon East
4   8800000.0   570     1              15.44  Borivali East
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
def func(element):
    
    num, type = element.split()
    
    if type == 'L' : return float(num) * 10**5
    if type == 'Cr': return float(num) * 10**7
```

```py
df['price'] = df['price'].apply(func)
```

Comment: happy to help! if you liked my answer you can accept it by clicking the tick on the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do it is to write a function to handle how you want to treat each element, and then use the map function on the relevant column:

```
def convert_price(price):
    price_value = float(price.split(" ")[0])
    if "L" in price:
        return price_value*100000
    elif "Cr" in price:
        return price_value*10000000
    else:
        return price  # or however else you want to handle it
    
df["price_converted"] = df["price"].map(convert_price)
```